# Getting started with ZXing on Android

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zxing

I'm trying to add ZXing to my project (add a button which calls the scanner upon press). I found this: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/788eb52a765c28b5 and of course the ZXing homesite: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/, but still couldn't figure out what to include in the project classpath to make it all work!

As for now, I copied the classes in the first link to my project (with some package name changes), and it runs but crashes after pressing the button and trying to install the barcode scanner.

Some code:

```
private void setScanButton(){
    Button scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MainPageScanButton);
    scan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(MyActivity.this);
        }
    });
}
```

Resulting error (from logcat):

```
06-13 15:26:01.540: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1423): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-13 15:26:01.560: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1423): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://search?q=pname:com.google.zxing.client.android }
```

Ideas?

Comment: BTW, I'm running on android emulator v1.6

Comment: I followed the directions as is from the Google Groups thread and it worked first time when I deployed it to my Samsung Galaxy S. I didn't even have to rename anything. In my project I let it create a new class path, "com.google.zxing.integration.andoid".

Comment: Try my blog, may help
http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/zxing-1-7-for-android-on-eclipse/

Answer (score 7):

Go [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/788eb52a765c28b5?pli=1) for links.

In the activity that you want to trigger a barcode scan include

```
IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(YourActivity.this);
```

and then also include:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
            TextView 
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
};
```

The Barcode Scanner app will handle the actual scanning. If the 
Barcode Scanner app is not installed, the integrator will prompt them 
to install it.

----------- From nEx.Software ---------------

Answer (score 3):

First, ZXing will not be able to automatically prompt the user to download from the Market on an emulator, because there is no Market on the emulator. You would need to manually install the Barcode Scanner APK on the emulator.

Second, since the emulator does not emulate a camera, Barcode Scanner probably will not do you much good. Most likely you are going to need to test this out on a device.

Comment: @Sean Owen: Sorry, somebody who didn't know what they were talking about edited my answer. I need to find out what sort of editing alerts there are in SO...

Comment: Erp yeah I figured out what happened after I commented. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code to your manifest file, within the `application` tag:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then add the following permission, if it has not already been added, at the top of file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your AndroidManifest whether you have given the "**android:name**" attributes correctly for the newly added Activities. You got "*ActivityNotFoundException*" it is mainly because you may have using a different package name and ZXing is using "**com.google.zxing.client.android**" package name. When you load the first Activity of the ZXing, give it the ***absolute class path*** not the relative path. Then your error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

barcode scanner application is not installed on your emulator which is giving this exception.Below link gives step by step guide how to install the 3rd party application on the emulator:

[Install application on emulator](http://www.androidaz.com/development/how-install-application-and-copy-files-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

if you use the zxing first time,I recommend this project**[1](http://code.google.com/p/android-quick-response-code/)**,it's a part of zxing, all you need is import the project and run it.This project is an attempt to make working with QR codes in Android a bit easier.
With strongly recommend to bigenner.good luck.
At last,thanks Sean Owen;

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on SD card for the emulator.
2. Copy link to BarcodeScaner found on [ZXing download page](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list)
3. Open browser in emulator and point to link edit box
4. Enter terminal and command 
   `adb shell input text 'https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=BarcodeScanner-4.5.1.apk&can=2&q='` - the link is link found on ZXing download page
5. Link copied to browser so you can download and install it. This solves described issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use Zxing in a tab (a Fragment) and use the support library (for Material Design components) so I had to call it like this:

IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
integrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan();

then in onActivityResult()

```
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE) {

            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            Log.i(TAG, "Barcode Result: " + contents);
            etc...
        }
    }
```

and in my Manifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It all works very nicely now. I was not successful just using intents and startActivityForResult(). The scanner would start and fix on the QRcode but did not return.

In my build.grade, I have:

repositories { mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/" }
}

```
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:2.0.0@aar'
compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-integration:2.0.0@aar'
```