# No activity found to handle intent{act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN cat=

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I got:
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No activity found to handle intent{ act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x4080000 pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android}
 when I run my own app integrated with zxing barcode scanner. There is no logcat.

First of all I downloaded source code from zxing and build it into an app and runs fine, then I turn it into a library for my app and run my app then got the error above. Here are how to turn zxing barcode scanner into a lib for my app:

I. on myapp's AndroidManifest.xml, add

```xml
<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
      android:stateNotNeeded="true"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

II. on myapp's MainActivity.java， I have this piece of code:

```java
      String package_name="com.google.zxing.client.android";

      Intent iScan = new Intent(package_name+".SCAN");

      iScan.setPackage(package_name);

      iScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

      iScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

      iScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

      iScan.putExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", 420);

      iScan.putExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", 420);

      iScan.putExtra("RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS", 3000L);

      iScan.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");

      iScan.putExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Scan the Contact");

           startActivityForResult(iScan, 0);
```

III. On my Project Properties->Android,

```
add  com.google.xing.client.android as lib and copy
```

com.google.xing.client.android.captureactivity.jar core.jar to libs dir of my app

Comment: Check this Lisnk

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15275082/2144920

Hope will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You do not add `android/`, or even `core/`, to your project if you are integrating by Intent. In fact this is strongly discouraged, mostly because of exactly what you've posted above: your app is saying it can handle Intents that Barcode Scanner is supposed to handle. That's not OK -- you're potentially intercepting calls to our app.

Since you are already integrating by Intent, don't bother with any of this. All you need is what is in `android-integration/`. See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

If you use `IntentIntegrator` as described there, it will handle installing the app so you don't trip over the `ActivityNotFoundException` you show above.

Comment: thanks. But if I use code: IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
       integrator.addExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", 420);
       integrator.addExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", 420);
       integrator.addExtra("RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS", 3000L);
       integrator.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Scan the Contact");
    integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES); it will still ask me to instal barcode scanner which is supposed to have been included in the lib

Comment: No, that's the point -- you don't need to include anything else. Barcode Scanner is not included. It will be installed on the device too. That way your users get the updates and can use Barcode Scanner+ too.

Answer (score -1):

You can resolve this error by installing Google Goggles in your mobile or any kind of supportive bar code scanning application(Zxing Barcode Scanner) . When you try to start the activity it will open through this application and feed data into your android app.

This worked for me :)